# How can I get COUNT in table1 based on some specific columns in table2

Tags: mysql, database, doctrine

I have the following tables:

**Post Table**

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| id | is_deleted | is_published |
+----+------------+--------------+
| 1  |     0      |      1       |
| 2  |     0      |      1       |
| 3  |     0      |      1       |
| 4  |     0      |      0       |
| 5  |     1      |      1       |
+----+------------+--------------+l
```

**Tag Table**

```
+----+---------+
| id |   name  |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Fashion |
| 2  | Tech    |
+----+---------+
```

**Post_Tag Table**

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | tag_id | post_id |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  |   2    |    2    |
| 2  |   2    |    3    |
| 3  |   1    |    2    |
| 3  |   1    |    4    |
| 3  |   1    |    1    |
| 4  |   1    |    5    |
+----+--------+---------+
```

From the above tables, the relationship between *tags* and *posts* are stored in the *post_tag* table.
Using the *post_tag* table, I want to count how many posts are tied to a *tag*. So I wrote this query to count posts for the fashion tag:

```
SELECT COUNT(tp.id) as totalPost FROM `post_tags` tp WHERE tag_id = 1;
```

This resulted in this which is correct for fashion tag:

```
+-----------+
| totalPost |
+-----------+
|    4      |
+-----------+
```

Now, my challenge is that:

1. post with *is_deleted* column = *true* should not be counted.
2. post with *is_published* column = *false* should not be counted.
3. if a post has both *is_deleted* and *is_published* columns as *true*, it should not be counted.

Hence, the query should count only when the post **is_published = true** and **is_deleted = false**.

Please, how do I achieve these?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `JOIN` the tables and use `WHERE` clause to filter out rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(tp.id) as totalPost
FROM post_tags tp
JOIN post p ON tp.post_id = p.id
WHERE tag_id = 1
AND p.is_deleted = 0
AND p.is_published = 1;
```